# Use IaC to get the private endpoint name created by front door, so I can automatically approve it?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

I have the following bicep that creates a frontdoor origin:

```
resource fdOrigin 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups/origins@2021-06-01' = {
  name: '$MyOrigin'
  parent: fdOriginGroup
  properties: {
    ...
    sharedPrivateLinkResource: {
      groupId: 'sites'
      privateLinkLocation: 'EastUS2'
      requestMessage: 'Please Approve This Bicep Request'
      status: 'Approved'
      privateLink: {
        id: appService.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This creates the private link, and then I can go to the app service and approve it. I need to approve it as part of the automated deployment.

Status approved, in the bicep above does not approve it. It is still in pending status in the app service.

However, I can approve it with this bicep:

```
resource privateEndpointConnection 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'my-app-service/ace50309-85b1-49f6-92c9-62bebeccecf3-13f6a331-6472-4497-bf94-67adaa467e35'
  properties: {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
          status: 'Approved' 
          description: 'Approved by pipeline'
      }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need the private endpoint name. I can get that name manually, after it's created, but how do I get it automatically during the deployment?

I don't see it being retuned by the origins bicep. I might be able to get it from the app service, but I don't see a way to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with PowerScript.

The [Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azprivateendpointconnection?view=azps-10.4.1) command will get all the private endpoints for the app service. Then I select the on that is pending and approve it.
I can approve it with the [Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/approve-azprivateendpointconnection?view=azps-10.4.1) command.

It's not the perfect solution. In theory, there could be multiple pending private endpoints. If anyone has a better idea, let me know.

Here is my PowerScript:

```
$appservice = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName rg-usas-IdP-dev-e2-001 -name app-usas-IdP-dev-e2-001

$pe = (Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -privatelinkresourceid $appservice.id | Where-Object {$_.ProvisioningState -like 'Pending'})

Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -Name $pe.name -ResourceGroup $ApplicationResourceGroup -ServiceName $ApplicationName  -PrivateLinkResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites
```